# Show Image on Notification (React Native) using amplify notification

Tags: react-native, push-notification, aws-amplify, aws-pinpoint

I am using @aws-amplify/push notification for push notification. I am able to receive notification but it does not show the image, even if the image is less than 1mb and the image is publicly available.
How do i get image on notification?
This is what i get now[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxdQ0.jpg)

How do i get this?[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrWKl.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently found out that @aws-amplify/push notification does not include images on notification for now. Image on notification have been added as a feature request.